# behaviour of atomic_add in opencl

Tags: opencl

I'm playing around with an example on opencl:

```
__kernel void atomic(__global int* x) {
   __local int a, b;
   a = 0; b = 0;
   a++;
   atomic_inc(&b);

   x[0] = a;
   x[1] = b;
   x[2]++;
   atomic_inc(x+3);
  }
```

Running this code with `global_size = 1024` and `workgroup_size = 8`, this is the following output:

```
[1 8 1 1024]
```

I can understand what is happening for all cases except the value given for `x[1]`. Why is the value of `x[1]` not 1024 but 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under `x[1]` is stored value of `b` which is a variable residing in `__local` address space meaning the variable is shared by all work items within a workgroup. Each of workgroup have `b` initialized to 0 and atomically incremented to 8 because workgroup size is 8 (each work item increments by 1).

Comment: how does the work items know that `__local int b` is the same variable when it is declared within the function? also, initially, b is being set to 0.

Comment: That's implementation detail. In your test `b` is accessed by all work items (race condition), you just don't see that because there is the same value being written by every work item. Normally you would use local buffer with size of workgroup size or restrict access to `b` to one work item at a time.